# Can shared memory be swapped out under memory pressure?

Tags: linux, memory-management, shared-memory

Under high memory pressure, if there are processes with massive shared memory, would linux swap out these shared memory pages just like it would regular memory pages?
Does swapping behavior differ for shared memory in any way?

What about when hugepages are being used by the process?
Would that make any difference in swapping policy under memory pressure?

Comment: Likely duplicates:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541420/when-and-how-is-mmaped-memory-swapped-in-and-out

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474946/are-sharing-a-memory-mapped-file-and-sharing-a-memory-region-implemented-based-o